# Load different php pages in a single div

Tags: javascript, html

how can i load my php pages on a single div block?
example on my index.php i have

```
<a>when i click this link it loads the home.php page on the div</a>
<a>when i click this link it loads the location.php page on the div</a>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at jQuery and the `.load()` function if you want to do it with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can use **.load** and **.html** functions to load respective pages into content div

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$('#content').load('home.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframes that work as "page content divs"

```
<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```